# django dev server not loading on google chrome

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-chrome, localhost, django-manage.py

I set up my first django server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` command. Why is google chrome not loading `localhost:8000/` for me even though Microsoft edge is?

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting the address that shows in the terminal when you start the server, e.g., `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. Maybe you are not adding the `http://` and it is not getting added automatically?

Comment: Other useful pieces of info: 

1) What version of django are you running?
2) What do you see in the window after running the command? It should look something like:

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 20, 2016 - 17:24:46
Django version 1.8.15, using settings 'MyProj.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to this problem.

in your local settings file add the following line:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', ]
```

Then you can access it by going to

```
0.0.0.0:8000
```